# Creating a scalable modify button on my website

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I'm looking to create a button for my website which allows the user to edit information on both the website and the database. To put it into context, I sell cars and when I would like to make changes to a vehicle's details, I would like it to update the information on the website, not just the database.

The function below represents what happens when the update button is clicked - I have narrowed it to just the car colour. The `content` piece represents the form which appears when the modify button is clicked. The `cars.colour` represents the colour of the car as per the DB. When the update button is clicked, this value will appear in the text field. The `#carList` is displayed on a different HTML page.

Catalogue.js:

```
function update(key){
  database.ref('car').once('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){
      snapshot.forEach(function(data){
        var cars = data.val();
        console.log(cars);

        if(data.key === key){
          var content = '';

          content += ' 
            <form id="car_update">
              <div class="container"> 
              <h1>Vehicle Details</h1>
              <div class="row"> 
                <input id="colour" 
                  type="colour" placeholder="Colour..." 
                  value="'**+cars.colour+**'" style="width: 150px;"/>
              </div>
              <button class="test" 
                onclick="updateCar(\''**+key+**'\')">Submit</button>'
        }

        $('#carList').append(content);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Item1.html:

```
<label>Colour: </label></br>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('colour').innerHTML;
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure I quite understand, it sounds like you want to make a call and update the database and you also want to the page display the user is seeing to update and you already have the call to the database working.

It looks like you have an inline javascript method in the html which is only called when the page is rendered by the browser:

```
<label>Colour: </label></br>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('colour').innerHTML;
</script>
```

If you want to also update the page from user input, I think you need to have the page refresh after the user submits so the html is called again from the server with the latest content that was updated in the database, *or* change the html to be setup in a way that it can be updated from the javascript, something like:

```
<label>Colour: </label></br>
<span id="colorLabel">
```

and then in the javascript, after cars.colour has the updated value, have something like:

```
  document.getElementById('colorLabel').innerHTML = cars.colour;
```